# Java remove text from a String using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to use the method **replaceAll** of the String class to extract a configuration path from a large String.
I managed to exclude the left side of the String with a regular expression, however I'm facing problems with the right side. Here is it:

```
/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/configuration", "jboss.server.data.dir" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/data", "jboss.server.deploy.dir" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/data/content", "jboss.server.log.dir" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/log", "jboss.server.name" : "fedora", "jboss.server.persist.config" : "true", "jboss.server.temp.dir" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/tmp", "line.separator" : "\n", "logging.configuration" : "file:/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties", "module.path" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/modules", "org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks" : "true", "org.jboss.boot.log.file" : "/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/log/server.log", "org.jboss.resolver.warning" : "true",
```

So I just want to capture the String **/home/user/qa/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/configuration**
and I have come up with this:

```
// String a contains the above text
String b = a.replaceAll("^\".*","");
System.out.println(b);
```

This is supposed to remove everything, beginning from the first occurrence of the quotes(").
However it does not work as expected as the full String is returned.
Anyone can help me to find out why?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need `^` start of string anchor here. try `".*"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! That leaves me a bit puzzled why the "^" character caused the expression to fail, but I will find it in the reg expr docs.

Comment: `^` means match must start from start of string, when you don't use `^` it will try to find first occurrence of `"` throughout the string and then proceed further with remaining pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Cutting off the start and the beginning of the string with two different regular expressions seems a bit inefficient to me. Take a look at [Regex groups](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm) and the Pattern / Matcher classes in the Java documentation, that way you can extract your target string without having to fire up a RegEx test twice.